# How can we call a soap web service if I have an xsl file and endpoint URL

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, soap, wsdl

I have to test a soap web service. But the files I have are one xsl file and an endpoint URL. When I tried to call this service using SoapUI, I have to import a wsdl which I don't have. 
Is there any way to call the webserivice with an xsl file and endpoint URL?
If wsdl is mandatory, how to get it?

XSL file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:v1="http://sample/standards/svcinfo/v1"  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
+<soapenv:Header>
+<soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: maybe the SOAP service does provide a way to query it for the wsdl?

Comment: Typically you would just go the url of the service and then ask it for the WSDL. If it is SOAP there will be a WSDL. For example if the url was http://www.foo.com/accountService you can possibly get the WSDL by asking using the following http://www.foo.com/accountService?wsdl however just ask the provider of the service for the WSDL you will need it.